# MongoDB Updates with Aggregation Pipeline Java Sync Driver

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-atlas

SO...

I am trying to write a single query to update and return multiple documents stored in an Atlas MongoDB ReplicaSet. Mongo version 7 and Java Sync Driver version 4.11.1 to build and execute the query.

[updateMany](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateMany/) is simple and straightforward, but it requires an additional query to retrieve the updated objects.

It seems like I want to use MongoDB's [Updates with Aggregation Pipeline](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/update-documents-with-aggregation-pipeline/) but I am having trouble getting it quite right, when I try to use ReplaceRoot with the following code...

```
final ReplaceRootOperation replaceRootOperation = Aggregation.replaceRoot(
    ObjectOperators.MergeObjects.merge(
        current(),
        new Document(myTimestampField, Instant.now())
    )
);

final AggregationResults<MyDatabaseModel> aggregationResults = 
    mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        Aggregation.newAggregation(matchOperation, replaceRootOperation),
        MyDatabaseModel.COLLECTION_NAME,
        MyDatabaseModel.class
    );

return aggregationResults.getMappedResults();
```

...this returns the updated documents with the appropriate timestamps, but it doesn't actually update the database and I get the same thing when I try to use $set.

I also tried using a `MergeOperation` instead, but I found that it wasn't respecting the matchOperation and instead my results included results that were not a part of the match (but only the matched ones were actually updated). I removed everything except the match to confirm that was working as expected, but for some reason, as soon as I add the merge operation, more documents were being returned. Maybe this is because the merge was using the `_id` field whereas the match was using other fields?

How can I update multiple documents and return them in Atlas MongoDB 7?

Comment: I think you need to use [Aggregation.newUpdate](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html#newUpdate(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.AggregationOperation...)). And, `mongoTemplate` is a Spring Data MongoDB API class.

Comment: Digging into this further, it seems that calling the "aggregate" function specifically never updates the collection unless you provide a "$merge" at the end of the pipeline as the examples in the Updates with Aggregation Pipeline reference, all of the queries are "update" ones.

Comment: It seems like there is a bug in the Java Sync Driver when a merge operation is part of the aggregation pipeline. I confirmed that the resulting JSON passed to the aggregation call is correct and works when put directly into the mongo shell, but when it is ran through the Java Sync Driver, while it works (i.e. updates the correct records), it returns ALL the records in the collections effectively ignoring any match operation in the pipeline.

Comment: `db.collection.bulkWrite()` is another way to update multiple documents and this returns the updated document ids. To return an updated document you need to use the `findAndModify`, `findOneAndReplace` or `findOneAndUpdate` constructs (note these update and return one document at a time).